# Mount Host Directory to Wildfly deployment directory

Tags: deployment, jboss, docker, wildfly

I am trying to find mount a host directory to the wildfly deployment directory in a Docker container.

The idea being that I can easily develop the code, and build it, and the running container will pick up the changes.

When I run the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it  -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 my/switchyard-dev -v /home/anton/workspaces/samples/jboss-kitchensink-angularjs/deploy/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

I get the following:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0

=========================================================================

13:00:29,919 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny"
```

And that is as far as it goes. Wildfly does not start.

When I run:

```
sudo docker run -it  -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 my/switchyard-dev
```

Wildfly starts as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, rearranging the order of the args seems to have solved it:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/anton/workspaces/samples/jboss-kitchensink-angularjs/deploy/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 my/switchyard-dev
```

Comment: I'm using wildfly and in my case is continuosly redeploying modules in a infinite loop